# pdo prepare escaping single quotes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use PDO in a web application I am building. I always thought (I am wrong actually) that using `prepare` should help with single quotes in the inserted variables but it seems that I miss something. I get an error inserting values like *L'Aquila* where there is a single quote in the input data.

My actual code is:

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO anagrafiche SET
        id_ndg = '$protocol',
        nick = '$nick',
        nome = '$nome',
        cognome = '$cognome',
        ragsoc = '$ragsoc',
        leg_rappr = '$leg_rappr',
        cod_fisc = '$cod_fisc',
        p_iva = '$p_iva',
        cf_estero = '$cf_estero',
        SAE = '$sae',
        RAE = '$rae',
        ATECO = '$ateco',
        CRCODE = '$crcode',
        indirizzo = '$indirizzo',
        civico = '$civico',
        cap = '$cap',
        citta = '$citta',
        prov = '$prov',
        tel = '$tel',
        cell = '$cellulare',
        mail = '$mail',
        note = '$note',
        file_ci = '$file_ci',
        file_cf = '$file_cf',
        file_visura = '$file_visura',
        cittadinanza = '$cittadinanza',
        res_fiscale = '$res_fiscale',
        is_curatore = '$is_curatore',
        is_legale = '$is_legale',
        is_tribunale = '$is_tribunale',
        is_fornitore = '$is_fornitore' ";
    try{
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);               
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        $error = 'Errori nel caricamento: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
```

and when I try to load a string containing the single quote I get an error like this while trying to load the string *Piazza d'Armi*
:

> Errori nel caricamento: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'Armi', civico = '0', cap = '83100', citta = 'Avellino',
>   prov' at line 15

What am I missing? I don't think that PDO quote can do the job for me but maybe it's me that I don't get the point

Comment: You already use `prepare()`, but not the actual variable binding. Look for `bindParam()` or the parameter to `execute()`.

Comment: Preparing is only step one. Binding is step 2. You should prepare a query with placeholders and bind the values to those placeholders. Preparing by itself is no more secure than just running the query by itself and is open to the same level of sql injection.

Comment: ah, ok. Should also do bindParam. Will give a try. Got the point on how prepare works now i think. Thanks!

Comment: You're doing it totally wrong... if you're preparing, you should be using placeholders. As is, you're still TOTALLY vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I know I am. This code is for an intranet app used by me to do massive load of sanitized data from an older application.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It helps with single quotes only if you do parametrized prepared statements, otherwise all you are doing is string concatenation and have to be subject to properly forming your SQL.

Try something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO anagrafiche SET
        id_ndg = :protocol,
        nick = :nick,
        nome = :nome,
        ...
        ";
$params = array(
    ':protocol' => $protocol,
    ':nick' => $nick,
    ':nome' => $nome,
    ...
); 
try{
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);               
    $s->execute($params);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    ...
}
```

This also gives you the added advantage of mitigating SQL injection attacks.

If you want to go a step further and enforce data types, you could use `bindValue()` or `bindParam()`

like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO anagrafiche SET
        id_ndg = :protocol,
        nick = :nick,
        nome = :nome,
        ...
        "; 
try{
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindParam(':protocol', $protocol, PDO::PARAM_ST);
    $s->bindParam(':nick', $nick, PDO::PARAM_ST);
    $s->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_ST);
    ...
    $s->bindParam(':some_integer', $some_integer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    ...           
    $s->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    ...
}
```

`bindValue()` has similar syntax to `bindParam()` but only binds the value of the variable at the time of binding to the parameter rather than the value of the variable at the time of statement execution.

Comment: should works also with bindParams, right? Listing all the string like `$s->bindParam(':protocol', $protocol)` ? I am asking just for my knowledge but this sintax is brilliant!!

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes. I added a `bindParam()` example here as well. I actually prefer `bindParam()` or `bindValue()` (depending on usage) to passing array in `execute()`, as I like to be specific about data types, but there are many who prefer passing the array at `execute()`