# Uable to unserialize a serialized string

Tags: php, serialization

I have an serialized string and I am trying to unserialized it, but getting false.

Serialized String echoed:

```
string(175) "a:6:{s:6:"tables";s:9:"8 Tables";s:8:"table_no";s:1:"6";s:6:"chairs";s:6:"Chairs";s:8:"chair_no";s:1:"6";s:12:"round_tables";s:11:"Round Table";s:14:"round_table_no";s:1:"6";}"
```

Data in database:

```
a:6:{s:6:"tables";s:9:"8 Tables";s:8:"table_no";s:1:"6";s:6:"chairs";s:6:"Chairs";s:8:"chair_no";s:1:"6";s:12:"round_tables";s:11:"Round Table";s:14:"round_table_no";s:1:"6";}
```

code to unserialize the data

```
var_dump(unserialize($fellowship_data['equipment']));
```

Data coming in post request before serializing it and saving to database

```
["equipment"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["tables"]=>
    string(9) "8' Tables"
    ["table_no"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["chairs"]=>
    string(6) "Chairs"
    ["chair_no"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["round_tables"]=>
    string(11) "Round Table"
    ["round_table_no"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["piping_drapes"]=>
    string(13) "Piping Drapes"
  }
```

Code before making it serialize

```
$equipment = array();
    if ( isset($_POST['equipment']) ){
        $equipment['tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['tables'] ) ? str_replace("'","", $_POST['equipment']['tables']) : '';
        $equipment['table_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['table_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['table_no'] : '';
        $equipment['chairs'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['chairs'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['chairs'] : '';
        $equipment['chair_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['chair_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['chair_no'] : '';
        $equipment['round_tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['round_tables'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['round_tables'] : '';
        $equipment['round_table_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['round_table_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['round_table_no'] : '';
    }
```

Code to serialize the data

```
$equipment = serialize($equipment);
```

Unserializing it returning `false`.

**Update**
*I changed the code and used json_encode and json_decode and stored in databsae as text, now while json decoding I am getting NULL!!*

Can any one give me some idea how it could be solved?

*If needed more information, please ask me question, so that I will add those to question.*

**Note:** *The server I am working on does not support `json` data type in its database, so I was bound to use serialize. I do not recommend people to follow it and use `serialize()` to save it.*

Comment: Can you include the actual code your using (minimal example)

Comment: @NigelRen Give me one minute, I am adding it.

Comment: @NigelRen please look it again I have added what ever I have done with it, let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: @xanadev thank you for your interest, my server is not updated configuration, does not support a lot of things, so I was bound to go with it. please look into last "note", I have mentioned.

Comment: yeah i deleted that comment :)

Comment: @xanadev Can you give some suggestion, how I could solve this in current situation?

Comment: The problem is here `s:9:"8 Tables"` as the content isn't 9 characters long.

Comment: i would encode it to json then store it as a text value, you can try that.

Comment: @NigelRen I understand that, but could not find any solution to it.

Comment: @xanadev I am not sure, if it will make things easier or more complex, but would surely try if could not find any solution with serialize. Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the DBMS you are using there are some advantages to storing your data as json as opposed to text. in case of mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: just in case you use json, to retrieve the data as an associative array make sure to call like so `json_decode($your_json_data, true);`

Comment: @xanadev Douglas Crockford originally specified the JSON format. :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170895/discussion-between-xanadev-and-prafulla-kumar-sahu).

Comment: @xanadev  I actually tried using json_encode and json_decode inplace of serialize and unserialize and look at the qusetion again,I have added  while using json_decode() I am getting null !

Comment: do a `json_last_error();` and see what errors it gives you.

Comment: @xanadev Obviously I have tried that, it was because the json that was getting generated having invalid syntax.Just solved it.

Comment: glad you did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because wrong serialize data is getting created from it.Even if we try to create JSON data, it is creating json data with wrong syntax.

If we will try bellow codes, PDO will not allow it.

1. `$equipment['tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['tables'] ) ? str_replace("'","", $_POST['equipment']['tables']) : '';`
2. `$equipment['tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['tables'] ) ? addslashes($_POST['equipment']['tables']) : '';`
3. `$equipment['tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['tables'] ) ? str_replace("'","\'", $_POST['equipment']['tables']) : '';`

results server error 500 in this case.

and

4. `$equipment['tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['tables'] ) ? addcslashes($_POST['equipment']['tables']) : '';` will results in NULL.

We can can use either of 2 and 3 and change our PDO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122058/pdo-prepare-escaping-single-quotes), that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the sample code you provided and it is correctly serializing the data.

**Expected result**:

```
string(175) "a:6:{s:6:"tables";s:8:"8 Tables";s:8:"table_no";s:1:"6";s:6:"chairs";s:6:"Chairs";s:8:"chair_no";s:1:"6";s:12:"round_tables";s:11:"Round Table";s:14:"round_table_no";s:1:"6";}"
```

The only difference between the expected and your result is that the content "8 Tables" is not 9 characters long.
Your original input (8' Tables) is actually 9 characters long with the character ' filtered out.
My best guess would be that your input gets serialized with the ' character and you are filtering it out after serializing.

**Here is the code snippet i ran**:

```
<?php

    $equipment = array();

    // Simulated post data from form submit
    $_POST["equipment"]["tables"] = "8' Tables";
    $_POST["equipment"]["table_no"] = "6";
    $_POST["equipment"]["chairs"] = "Chairs";
    $_POST["equipment"]["chair_no"] = "6";
    $_POST["equipment"]["round_tables"] = "Round Table";
    $_POST["equipment"]["round_table_no"] = "6";
    $_POST["equipment"]["piping_drapes"] = "Piping Drapes";


    if ( isset($_POST['equipment']) ){
        $equipment['tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['tables'] ) ? str_replace("'","", $_POST['equipment']['tables']) : '';
        $equipment['table_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['table_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['table_no'] : '';
        $equipment['chairs'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['chairs'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['chairs'] : '';
        $equipment['chair_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['chair_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['chair_no'] : '';
        $equipment['round_tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['round_tables'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['round_tables'] : '';
        $equipment['round_table_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['round_table_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['round_table_no'] : '';
    }

    $equipment = serialize($equipment);
    var_dump($equipment);
    var_dump(unserialize($equipment));

?>
```

**Using JSON to serialize your data**:

If you decide on using json to serialize your data there is actually not a lot of a difference in the code necessary.
You use "json_encode" just like "serialize" and "json_decode" similar to "unserialize". The most important note on [decoding json data in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is that you are able to decide if you want an object or an associative  array. As you would want an array the decode function would be json_decode($data, **true**).

**Example using JSON**:

```
<?php

    $equipment = array();

    // Simulated post data from form submit
    $_POST["equipment"]["tables"] = "8' Tables";
    $_POST["equipment"]["table_no"] = "6";
    $_POST["equipment"]["chairs"] = "Chairs";
    $_POST["equipment"]["chair_no"] = "6";
    $_POST["equipment"]["round_tables"] = "Round Table";
    $_POST["equipment"]["round_table_no"] = "6";
    $_POST["equipment"]["piping_drapes"] = "Piping Drapes";


    if ( isset($_POST['equipment']) ){
        $equipment['tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['tables'] ) ? str_replace("'","", $_POST['equipment']['tables']) : '';
        $equipment['table_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['table_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['table_no'] : '';
        $equipment['chairs'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['chairs'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['chairs'] : '';
        $equipment['chair_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['chair_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['chair_no'] : '';
        $equipment['round_tables'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['round_tables'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['round_tables'] : '';
        $equipment['round_table_no'] = isset( $_POST['equipment']['round_table_no'] ) ? $_POST['equipment']['round_table_no'] : '';
    }

    $equipment = json_encode($equipment);
    var_dump($equipment); // Encoded data as json string
    var_dump(json_decode($equipment, true)); // Associative array with the decoded data

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort "filtering it out after serializing." , I am filtering out before serializing it, I think there is some issue while it is getting returned from database, I am going through your code, I hope will get some idea.

Comment: I actually saw that your are filtering it out while assigning it to the $equipment array but maybe your are assigning it twice somewhere because you forgot to remove debug code. As you mentioned it could also originate from the database so I hope you figure out what really happened.

Comment: I actually tried using json_encode and json_decode inplace of serialize and unserialize and look at the qusetion again,I have added  while using json_decode() I am getting null ! Now it is confirm there is something about that "8\ Tables" that is causing problem and I am unable to get correctly.

Comment: If possible could you provide the whole php file which is handling your data input?